# Selecting SVG with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, dc.js

I have the following function:

```
function myfunc(d) {
  var svg = d3.select('.map-wrap svg');
  console.log('svg is:');
  console.log(svg);

  // interesting stuff happens later ...
}
```

I call that function on a `mouseover` event. Here is code where `myfunc` is supposed to be called.

```
myChart.width(800)
    .height(800)
    .dimension(xDim)
    .group(xDimGrp)
    .projection(projection)
    .colors(quantize)
  .colorDomain(quantize.domain())
  .colorCalculator(function (d) { return d ? getColorClass(myChart.colors()(d)) : '#ccc'; })
    .overlayGeoJson(map.features, 'states', function (d) {
        return d.properties.state;
    }).on('mouseover', myfunc);
```

When I print out `svg` I expect to see this:

[image: svg object in array]

instead, I see the following:

[image: svg is null]

I see `0: null` instead of `0: svg`, why is this happening? How can I select the SVG in a way that will give me what is shown in first picture?

`.map-wrap` is like so:

[image: map wrapper div]

Comment: can we see the .map-wrap element?

Comment: @echonax updated Q with what you requested. Thx

Comment: may be when you calling the function svg may not have been created

Comment: Seems to work as expected http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/pee555cb/

Comment: I've added some more code. Am I right with my way of handling the `mouseover` event? This is with `dc.js`.

Comment: Following your code is there anywhere you are removing svg because your code looks good.

Answer (score 0):

It was as Cyril said, after debugging better, I realised that it was indeed being called before the creation of the `svg` element.